# How to read the output Tensor (tflite) in android studio

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I can get the shape and read the tensors itself in python but can only get shape of the tensors using
tflite.getOutputTensor(0).shape() and tflite.getInputTensors(0).shape() in android tflite. i read the tensors using
.get_tensor(nodevalue) in python but how am i supposed to do this in android

[My input and output tensors in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSnhS.png)

[Getting only shapes in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIkQM.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign output buffers to the interpreter prior to invocation. See following link for example code.

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/ee198ec873148a5df3fd6eedb8d396613164ead7/lite/examples/image_classification/android/lib_support/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/Classifier.java#L258

Or for multiple outputs,

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/ee198ec873148a5df3fd6eedb8d396613164ead7/lite/examples/object_detection/android/lib_interpreter/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/tflite/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java#L202